# Vertically and Horizontally Center Text Responsively

Tags: css, html, centering

I'm trying to make a website using a parallax jquery pluin, and i would like the first 'slide' to be a title which is right in the center of the screen.

I've been struggling to do this - horizontally aligning it is simple however I can't vertically align it.

Is there a way to do this which works and is also responsive? I've included a fiddle, to show you the basic structure - http://jsfiddle.net/SohamK/yKDWS/1/. I have also reproduced the html of the fiddle below:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="title">
    <h1> My Title </h1>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display` property like this:

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:table;
    text-align:center;
 }
.title {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/yKDWS/13/**

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
$('h1').css({
    'position' : 'absolute',
    'left' : '50%',
    'top' : '50%',
    'margin-left' : -$(this).width()/2,
    'margin-top' : -$(this).height()/2
  });
});
```

Try this with jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS property `display:table`, and use `vertical-align:middle` & `text-align:center`. This is perfectly center your text vertically and horizontally in your div.

Your div `.container` will have a `display:table`, and your div `.title` will have a `display:table-cell` with the property `vertical-align:middle`.

Check [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3atable) for display:table browser compatibility.

Full CSS will look like this -

```
.container {
    display:table;
 }
.title {
    text-align:center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically this would always align it to vertical middle

```
  .title
    {
        margin-top:25%;
    }
```

[**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/yKDWS/3/)

Whats the exact markup for you page, it depends on that.

If the above demo solves it, its fine, else markup would be required!! :)

Comment: At the minute, that is all I have. I tried changing the margin-top but it is not exactly in the center. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this : [**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/yKDWS/15/)

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    background:#333;
    display: table;
}

.title {
    color:#fff;
    padding:0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```